python multiprocessing.Pool.map doesn't speed up the code for partial function
I am trying to do a resampling task, and I try to use multiprocessing to speed up the code. My purpose is to speed up the code like this:
import numpy as np
def jackknife_resampling(value, weight, label):
    # label is an integer array, marking the subsample
    def _resample(i):
        _value = value[label != i]
        _weight = weight[label != i]
        return np.average(_value, weights=_weight)
    return list(map(_resample, np.unique(label)))

To use multiprocessing, I need to substitute the map with Pool.map, and move the function _resample out.
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Pool
def _resample(value, weight, label, i):
    _value = value[label != i]
    _weight = weight[label != i]
    return np.average(_value, weights=_weight)
def jackknife_resampling_mp(value, weight, label, Npro):
    my_pool = Pool(Npro)
    return my_pool.map(partial(_resample, value, weight, label), np.unique(label))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Nsamp = 1_0_000_000
    value = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=Nsamp)
    weight = np.random.uniform(1, 2, size=Nsamp)
    label = np.random.randint(0, 200, size=Nsamp)
    t = time.time()
    jackknife_resampling_mp(value, weight, label, 40)
    print('time', time.time()-t)

Because _resample function still needs the original value and weight, so I used partial to pass  to it. But it turns out that it didn't speed up the code. To prove Pool.map actually works, I use global variable and it works well.
def _resample(i):
    global value, weight, label
    _value = value[label != i]
    _weight = weight[label != i]
    return np.average(_value, weights=_weight)

def jackknife_resampling_mp(_value, _weight, _label, Npro):
    global value, weight, label
    value = _value
    weight = _weight
    label = _label
    # label is a integer array, marking the subsample
    my_pool = Pool(Npro)
    return my_pool.map(_resample, np.unique(label))

this works, but I think it is pretty ugly. PS: I also tried warping the whole resampler into a class, which is the same case as I used partial(I use python 3.12 so that instance method can be pickled).
Why is that? And is there better way to do it?

Your first sample has 240 megabytes of data that has to be shipped to each of the child processes over a socket.  Your second example has the data in a global, and the child processes DO inherit the initial memory space, at least on Linux.  On Windows, it would be just as bad.

Yeah, and it's worth noting that the copy-on-write behavior of fork is brittle in Python because a lot of operations that you don't think are a "write" may actually end up doing that, e.g. changing a reference count

I think this is helpful for you.
import numpy as np
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool, shared_memory

def _resample(shared_value_name, shared_weight_name, label, i, shape):
    #CREATING SHARED MEMORY....
    shm_value = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shared_value_name)
    shm_weight = shared_memory.SharedMemory(name=shared_weight_name)

    value = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=np.float64, buffer=shm_value.buf)
    weight = np.ndarray(shape, dtype=np.float64, buffer=shm_weight.buf)

    _value = value[label != i]
    _weight = weight[label != i]
    return np.average(_value, weights=_weight)

def jackknife_resampling_mp(value, weight, label, Npro):
    #CREATING SHARED MEMORY...
    shm_value = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=value.nbytes)
    shm_weight = shared_memory.SharedMemory(create=True, size=weight.nbytes)

    np.copyto(np.ndarray(value.shape, dtype=value.dtype, buffer=shm_value.buf), value)
    np.copyto(np.ndarray(weight.shape, dtype=weight.dtype, buffer=shm_weight.buf), weight)

    try:
        with Pool(Npro) as pool:
            results = pool.starmap(_resample, 
                [(shm_value.name, shm_weight.name, label, i, value.shape) for i in np.unique(label)])
    finally:
        shm_value.close()
        shm_weight.close()
        shm_value.unlink()
        shm_weight.unlink()

    return results

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Nsamp = 1_000_000
    value = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=Nsamp)
    weight = np.random.uniform(1, 2, size=Nsamp)
    label = np.random.randint(0, 200, size=Nsamp)

    t = time.time()
    results = jackknife_resampling_mp(value, weight, label, 40)
    print('time', time.time() - t)

Thanks

To enhance it performance you should use PyPy Python's Project to reduce overheads as Traditional Python (CPython) bcz CPython doesn't have JIT (Just-In-Time) Compilation which enhance reduces performance but PyPy compiles Frequent Used Segment Code(Loops, Function) and use it regather than CPython (Read Bytecode and compile it again-2) so it helps you to enhance performance.
